# Autohotkey: react to a short Shift press (LShift or RShift)

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to make a script that would react to a short LShift press and send the "(". It should only happen if LShift is pressed shortly. If it is pressed for a longer than 500ms, for example, then it should not send anything and continue working as a regular LShift.

This way I want to utilize the short Shift press that does not do anything for now.
I tried to experiment with KeyWait but it did not really work. Do I need to introduce the timer variable or is there an easier way of doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like that:

```
~LShift::
    KeyWait, LShift
    if  A_TimeSinceThisHotkey <= 500
        Send, (
return
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to lower time to 150, since typing "I", for example really fast triggers the scrip as well. Is there a way to cancel the KeyWait if while holding LShift another key was pressed?